# Use sequentialfs with SVM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, feature-selection

Can somebody help me with "sequentialfs "?

I'm failing to use it with the following SVM functions. 'X' contains the features for each observation and 'y' contains the classes of each observation.

```
SVMModel = fitcsvm(X,Y);
predict(SVMModel, X);
```

When executing sequentialfs, the following error occurs:

The function 'featureSelection' generated the following error:
Too many input arguments.

Here, my code:

```
fs = sequentialfs(@featureSelection,X,y)

function err=featureSelection(X,y)
    SVMModel = fitcsvm(X,y,'KernelFunction','gaussian', 'KernelScale','auto');
    err = 0;
    for i=1:size(X,1)
         err = err + (y(i) ~= predict(SVMModel,X(i,:)));
    end 
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. According to MATLAB's documentation:

> *sequentialfs* performs 10-fold cross-validation by repeatedly calling
>   fun with different training subsets of X and y, XTRAIN and ytrain, and
>   test subsets of X and y, XTEST and ytest, as follows:
>
> criterion = fun(XTRAIN,ytrain,XTEST,ytest)

That means that your criterion function should follow the form:

```
function err=featureSelection(XTRAIN,ytrain,XTEST,yTest)
```

as long as *sequentialfs* will by default separate your X data to XTRAIN and XTEST subsets.

Below is an example:

```
c = cvpartition(Labels,'Holdout',0.3);
opts = statset('display','iter');
classf = @(train_data,train_labels,test_data,test_labels) ...
       sum(predict(fitcsvm(train_data,train_labels,'KernelFunction','rbf'), test_data) ~= test_labels); 
[fs,history] = sequentialfs(classf,Data,Labels,'cv',c,'options',opts)
```